# Can second hand SIM locked iPhone 4S be activated with a different carrier?

Tags: iphone, unlock, ios

I have my first experience with an iPhone, so really need some guidance and advice. I have got a second hand iPhone 4S - OS 5.1.1. I was told that it is SIM locked to a certain network.

When I switched it on it had *Apple's Terms & Conditions* on the screen which I had to accept or decline to proceed. After restart it asks me to insert a *"valid sim card"*.

Questions:

1. I am wondering if this is standard to get T&C on the screen after restore or this phone never been activated?
2. If this iPhone has never been activated - can it be activated with a different carrier's SIM card to what it was supposed to be locked to?
3. If I try to activate it with a SIM card from a different carrier - what is the chance that it stops working and becomes a "brick"?

Comment: I have a feeling some of those questions could be hard to answer without getting a little more specific. It is normal to need to accept T&Cs after restoring. I have heard that at least AT&T will unlock if it was an AT&T phone which would allow it to be used with T-Mobile, for example. I would call the carrier you want to be on, and the one it is "locked" to.

Answer (score 1):

> 1 Question: I am wondering if this is standard to get T&C on the
>   screen after restore or this phone never been activated?

Yes it is standard to get the T&C after restore.

> 2 Question: If this iPhone has never been activated - can it be
>   activated with a different carrier's SIM card to what it was supposed
>   to be locked to?

Activation is irrelevant.  You'll either need to jail break the phone and unlock it, or ask the carrier the phone was intended for to unlock it.

> 3 Question: If I try to activate it with a SIM card from a different
>   carrier - what is the chance that it stops working and becomes a
>   "brick"?

No, inserting a SIM card from another carrier won't "brick" it.  It just won't work in the phone.

Something to consider, the iPhone 4S uses a smaller sim card than standard phones do.  When upgrading to a 4S from a 3GS I had to sand my SIM card down to fit (I like to use prepaid service so I'm not under a contract).

Comment: If your carrier won't unlock the phone then you can probably find a person willing to do it for you on eBay. Since the phone is second hand you can still legally unlock it in the US. I have done two cell phone unlocks on eBay, both for under $7, both worked very well.